# How to choose an option from a non select dropdown menu in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to click dropdown menu button in this html code.

```
<div id="menu-button-:r1p:" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-:r1p:" class="chakra-menu__menu-button css-6iqp1a" data-active="">
<span class="css-xl71ch">
<div class="css-70qvj9">Aa
</div>
</span>
</div>

<div class="css-r6z5ec" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; min-width: max-content; inset: 0px auto auto 0px;">
<div tabindex="-1" role="menu" id="menu-list-:rt:" aria-orientation="vertical" class="chakra-menu__menu-list css-17zw3g2" style="transform-origin: var(--popper-transform-origin); opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform: scale(0.8) translateZ(0px);">
<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 12px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:ru:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="0" aria-disabled="false">12</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 13px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:rv:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="1" aria-disabled="false">13</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 14px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r10:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="2" aria-disabled="false">14</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 15px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r11:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="3" aria-disabled="false">15</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 16px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r12:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="4" aria-disabled="false">16</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 17px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r13:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="5" aria-disabled="false">17</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 18px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r14:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="6" aria-disabled="false">18</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 19px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r15:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="7" aria-disabled="false">19</button>

<button type="button" aria-label="Font size 20px" id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r16:" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="chakra-menu__menuitem css-13c7rae" data-index="8" aria-disabled="false">20</button>

</div>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-list-:rt:-menuitem-:r15:"]')
```

also with :

```
find_element(By.ID, 'menu-button-:rt:')
```

but it says:

```
no such element, unable to locate element.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the URL, cannot debug this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the dropdown menu element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.chakra-menu__menu-button[id^='menu-button'][aria-controls^='menu-list'] > span").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'chakra-menu__menu-button')][starts-with(@id, 'menu-button') and starts-with(@aria-controls, 'menu-list')]/div").click()
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.chakra-menu__menu-button[id^='menu-button'][aria-controls^='menu-list'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'chakra-menu__menu-button')][starts-with(@id, 'menu-button') and starts-with(@aria-controls, 'menu-list')]/div"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```